# Get row only if row contains a column with a value less than 1

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

I cannot change the DB schema/design easily, so I need help with the following situation.

There is one row for each object with its own unique ID (matches table primary key - guaranteed to only be one row at most).

```
id (int; prim key),field1 (int), field2 (int), ...... (int), fieldn (int)
```

I want to do something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 AND ANY_FIELD < 1`. Obviously, this doesn't exist. The row contains a low of columns (several dozen - thus I cannot do `WHERE field1 < 1 Or field2 < 1 OR ...` easily at all).

I thought about doing something like `SELECT * FROM (DESC table A) WHERE A.Field.Value < 1` (.Value does not exist though).

I would like only one query (fine with sub-queries).

How it does right now is that it scans each column and check it manually, very slow.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: i think you should write out the OR conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that is not possible. You could construct a prepared statement with all columns dynamically and then execute that. But that cannot achieved within a single query. You would have to create the dynamic statement, then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

As a long shot: you could get all the field-names from the information schema, to make a SUM of all rows (see [this random google hit](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/mysql/threads/166793/select-sum-all-fields-in-table) ). If you substract the `ID`, you have a total of all rows you are looking for.

This gets you close, but still 0+0+3 is still three, so you can't just check if the total number of rows is more then the SUM -> you need to add some checks in this query yourself to fix that, but I believe that might be doable. (either something that only checks <0 rows and adds those, or some form of IF that counts >1 as 1)

In case the link disapears: this is the query from that forum that adds all integer rows.

```
SET @qry = (SELECT CONCAT('SELECT SUM(',GROUP_CONCAT(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR '+'), ')
 FROM ',INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME,' 
 WHERE date_column BETWEEN \'2008-01-01\' AND \'2008-12-31\' ')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE = 'int');
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the answer @Nanne gave, but this query will build the where clause like you describe with col1 < 1 or col2 < 1 ....

```
SET @qry = (SELECT CONCAT('SELECT * FROM table1 where ',GROUP_CONCAT(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ' < 1 or '), ' < 1')
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = 'table1'
                  AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME != 'id'
                  AND INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE = 'int');
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt
```

Here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcfbf/1) (This site has been up and down all day)

Comment: Thanks. It is unfortunate since it is definitely still not very efficient. I know SQL shouldn't cater to bad schema design, but it would be nice to have a feature like I described.